# Is it correct to use correlation coefficient in this case?

Tags: correlation, exponential-distribution

I have an exponential random variable $\tau$. I define two random variables $T_A=\min(t_1,\tau)$ and $T_B=\min(t_2,\tau)$, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are constants. What does it mean to compute $\rho(T_A,T_B)$? Is the relationship between these two variables 'linear' in the sense that causation will ensure a correlation of 1?

Comment: This definition of "linear" is not in common usage.  In fact, it would very rarely be the case that *anything* is linear!

Comment: Is this a survival analysis context?

Answer (score 1):

The value you get from the correlation coefficient is a number between -1 and 1, where 0 represents no matching, -1 negative linear and 1 positive linear matching.[image: The correlation coefficient]

'linear' means all values you feed into the algorithm which lay on one straight line are matching. For example, A(1/2) and B(2/4) would be matching 100%.